# How can one implement OpenableColumns for a pre-existing table?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider

I have a SQLite table which holds references to my app's internal files. This table maintains the file's internal file name, the file's mime type (as a file extension, e.g. "wav"), and a human-friendly title (e.g. "initial thoughts"). My `ContentProvider`, in `openFile()`, queries this table to find the internal file name, and then provides a stream of the file to whomever requested it.

I want to implement `OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME` so that if requested, the ContentProvider can return a meaningful file name, based on the title + a dot + the extension. The above example would, therefore, result in a display name of "initial thoughts.wav".

Since there is no column that directly corresponds to `OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME`, how can I set up my ContentProvider's `query()` method to return the appropriately calculated `DISPLAY_NAME` value for each record, along with any of the other regular columns that may be requested?

For other calls to openFile() I have implemented `OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME` through constructing a `MatrixCursor` with one row; however, I don't see how this would work, since I need to return multiple rows for the query, with a mixture of columns already present in the table, and psuedo-columns created on the fly.

I want, therefore, to be able to query for, say, `{FilesTable.INTERNAL_FILE_NAME, OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME}`, and get a meaningful result from my `ContentProvider`.

Comment: So you want to concatenate the values in two columns?

Comment: @CL. Nearly. There needs to be an extension separator character between the two column values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an SQL query like this to create a pseudo column:

```
SELECT _id,
       InternalFileName,
       FileType,
       Title,
       Title || '.' || FileType AS DisplayName
FROM MyLittleTable
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought SQL aliasing might be a possibility, but was unsure how to use it with `buildQuery()`. For the reference of others, here's an example of your solution in Java: `String[] projection = {MyLittleTable.COLUMN_ID, MyLittleTable.INTERNAL_FILE_NAME, MyLittleTable.COLUMN_TITLE + " || '.' || " + MyLittleTable.COLUMN_FILETYPE + " AS " + OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME };` - this can then be passed into `SQLiteQueryBuilder`'s `buildQuery()` method as the `projection` parameter.